# Multithreaded API - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I'd like to know if there is possible to build a multithreaded API using NodeJS. I have read about `worker_threads` and seems like it's what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to have an endpoint that processes requests with multiple threads.

```
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');

// this is my /insert endpoint
const insert = async (ctx, req) => {
    const records = req.data;

    try {
        const port = new Worker('./worker.js', {workerData : {records: records}});
        port.on('message', console.log);
    } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
    }
};
```

And this is my Worker.js

```
const {parentPort, workerData} = require('worker_threads');
const {insertProfile} = require('../repository');


(async ({records}) => {
    const results = await Promise.all(records.map(async (records) => {
        return insertProfile(records);
    }));
    parentPort.postMessage(results.length);
    // return results.length;
})({records: workerData.records});
```

As you can see in every request I'm creating a new `Worker`. That's not optional since I expect thousands of requests so in a while my responses become very slow. What I want to do is to have for example 10 threads `Worker` and reuse them in every request, is this possible in NodeJS?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `BullMQ` npm package to use queue of worker threads.